# What happens if elasticache memory capacity is exceeded?

Tags: redis, amazon-elasticache

I have a cache.t4g.micro cluster which has with 0.5 GiB memory (I assume this is RAM memory).

What happens if I try to add more data than that? Would that be written to HDD/SSD storage (but the docs don't mention such storage, only RAM), or would `StringSetAsync()` simply fail? Or maybe the oldest key/value pair would be removed from the cache to make room?

Basically what happens if storage capacity is exceeded in ElastiCache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redis keeps its entire dataset in memory ([why?](https://redis.io/docs/getting-started/faq/#why-does-redis-keep-its-entire-dataset-in-memory)).

Redis behavior [when memory storage is exceeded](https://redis.io/docs/getting-started/faq/#what-happens-if-redis-runs-out-of-memory) depends on `maxmemory-policy` configuration ([documentation here](https://redis.io/docs/manual/eviction/)).

Possible values for `maxmemory-policy` are (source: redis.conf):

- volatile-lru -> remove the key with an expire set using an LRU algorithm
- allkeys-lru -> remove any key according to the LRU algorithm
- volatile-random -> remove a random key with an expire set
- allkeys-random -> remove a random key, any key
- volatile-ttl -> remove the key with the nearest expire time (minor TTL)
- noeviction -> don't expire at all, just return an error on write operations

When it comes to AWS ElastiCache, Redis engine is configured via [Parameter Groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/ParameterGroups.Management.html).

The default parameter group `default.redis6.x` for example specifies a value of `volatile-lru` for `maxmemory-policy` but you can create your own parameter group and change this value as you see fit.